# not able to render phtml file magento 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1, blocks, phtml

this is my config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ilogix_Regionbased>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Ilogix_Regionbased>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <regionbased>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Ilogix_Regionbased</module>
                    <frontName>ilogix_regionbased</frontName>
                </args>
            </regionbased>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <regionbased>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Ilogix_Regionbased</module>
                    <frontName>ilogix_regionbased</frontName>
                </args>
            </regionbased>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <regionbased>
                <class>Ilogix_Regionbased_Helper</class>
            </regionbased>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <ilogix_regionbased>
                <!-- Set a block definition and lookup directory -->
                <class>Ilogix_Regionbased_Block_Adminhtml_Regionbased</class>
            </ilogix_regionbased>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <regionbased>
                    <file>ilogix/regionbased.xml</file>
                </regionbased>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <menu>
            <catalog module="adminhtml">
                <children>
                    <regionbased module="regionbased">
                        <title>Regions</title>
                        <sort_order>181</sort_order>
                        <action>ilogix_regionbased/adminhtml_index</action>
                    </regionbased>
                </children>
        </catalog>
        </menu>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

this is my block file /app/code/local/Ilogix/Regionbased/Block/Adminhtml/Regionbased.php

```
class Ilogix_Regionbased_Block_Adminhtml_Regionbased extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

this is my layout xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<layout>
        <regionbased_adminhtml_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template"  name="regions" template="regionbased/index.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </regionbased_adminhtml_index_index>
</layout>
```

Here when I use block type="core/template" it perfectly renders my phtml file but when I try to use block type="regionbased/adminhtml_regionbased" it does not render the phtml file . not sure what am I doing wrong here . Please help!

Thanks

Comment: Pls try : type ="ilogix_regionbased/adminhtml_regionbased"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**layout xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<layout>
    <regionbased_adminhtml_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="regionbased/adminhtml_regionbased"  name="regions" template="regionbased/index.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </regionbased_adminhtml_index_index>
</layout>
```

**block file:**

```
<?php

class Ilogix_Regionbased_Block_Adminhtml_Regionbased extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

}
```

**config.xml file**

```
 <global>
        <blocks>
            <regionbased>
                <class>Ilogix_Regionbased_Block</class>
            </regionbased>
        </blocks>
 </global>
```

Comment: thanks @Abdul , I was doing it in a wrong way I changed   <blocks>
            <ilogix_regionbased>
                <!-- Set a block definition and lookup directory -->
                <class>Ilogix_Regionbased_Block</class>
            </ilogix_regionbased>
        </blocks>

I am trying your answer as well .